# Need to sort array based on another array of array

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays which are to be compared and sorted based on another array. Here is as follows:

```
a = [["A", 1075000], ["C", 1750000], ["D", 0], ["E", 0], ["B", 0]]
b = ['A','B','C','D','E']
```

The array `a` should be sorted in order as follows(in which a is compared with `b`):

```
[["A", 1075000], ["B", 0], ["C", 1750000], ["D", 0], ["E", 0]]
```

I have tried this:

```
sort_by a.sort! {|a1,b1| a1[0] <=> b1[0]}
```

Comment: yes i am using sort_by    a.sort! {|a1,b1| a1[0] <=> b1[0]}
 , i am missing something

Comment: will the desired output remain same if `b = [B,A,C,D,E]` ?

Comment: @shivam : giving different outputs  based on array a values , and output was fine if b = [B,A,C,D,E]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to sort the elements in `a` according to their position in `b` and that the elements in `b` are the strings `'A'`, `'B'`, etc and not constants.

Then I would do something like this:

```
a = [["A", 1075000], ["C", 1750000], ["D", 0], ["E", 0], ["B", 0]]
b = ['A','B','C','D','E']

a.sort { |x, y| b.index(x.first) <=> b.index(y.first) }
#=> [["A", 1075000], ["B", 0], ["C", 1750000], ["D", 0], ["E", 0]]
```

Depending on the size of `b` it might make sense to use `sort_by` instead of `sort`. `sort_by` catches the return value of the block and does not evaluate the block multiple times:

```
a.sort_by { |x| b.index(x) }
```

Comment: +1, however, I believe it would be faster to build a hash out of `b`, because for a large `b`, hash lookup would be faster than array scan. You pay some cost in per-processing and gain speed in performance.

Comment: This block given to `.sort` is used n*log(n) times. `b.index` is O(n)`. So performance here will scale poorly as `a` and `b` grow large.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy : I agree that this solution does not scale well for large arrays. In the other hand building a lookup table and adding more lines of code for only 5 elements does not feel right too. I think the decision which solution is preferred depends on the size of the problem and only the OP can make that call.

Comment: Sure, but why not `a.sort_by{|x,y| b.index x }` as  a compromise?

Comment: @spickermann : How to combine array of Hashes into single hash?

Comment: @spickermann : for eg : [{"Call"=>1}, {"Breakfast meeting"=>3}, {"Breakfast meeting"=>1}]  should be to [{"Call"=>1}, {"Breakfast meeting"=>4}]

Comment: @Ranzit: Please ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this:

```
lookup = {}
b.each_with_index { |el, i| lookup[el] = i }
a.sort_by { |el| lookup.fetch(el.first) }
# => [["A", 1075000], ["B", 0], ["C", 1750000], ["D", 0], ["E", 0]]
```

Comment: also `lookup = b.each_with_index.to_h`